# Convert date to next 10th minute

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table of events each row has a `Start Time` and `End Time` but I want to count the number of seconds an Event is active in a 10 minute period.

**TABLE**

```
StartTime             EndTime                 AssetID   EventID
.........              ........              .......    ........
2014/12/01 10:29:50   2014/12/01 10:32:09     10       10045
2014/12/01 10:29:55   2014/12/01 10:45:10     11       10046
2014/12/01 10:33:12   2014/12/01 11:01:45     10       10047
```

**Desired Output:-**

```
     Time              DurationActiveSeconds      AssetID         EventID
.................      ....................      .........        .......   
2014/12/01 10:30:00       10                         10           10045
2014/12/01 10:30:00       5                          11           10046
2014/12/01 10:40:00       129                        10           10045
2014/12/01 10:40:00       408                        10           10047
2014/12/01 10:40:00       600                        11           10046
2014/12/01 10:50:00       600                        10           10047
2014/12/01 10:50:00       310                        11           10046
2014/12/01 11:00:00       600                        10           10047
2014/12/01 11:10:00       105                        10           10047
```

I would like to end up with Time Stamp of 10 intervals for each `AssetID` and `EventID` where the duration is worked out in seconds for the period an event is active, I am running this for a period of a month, if an event started in the previous month the the count would start from midnight on the 1st.

I have already built a calender table with an entry for each second but can't work out how to group the data as I need it.

**Edited Details**
If I take the first row of data, asset 10 stopped working at 10:29:50 and started working again at 10:32:09, what I want to see as my result set is two time periods at ten minute intervals:-
10:30 and 10:40 with 10 seconds deducted from 600 (number of seconds in 10 minutes) for the 10:30 period and 129 seconds deducted from the 600 for the 10:40 period. providing a table as below:-

```
    EndPeriod        Asset  Event  Duration
   ...........       .....  .....  ........
2014/12/01 10:30:00   10    10045    590
2014/12/01 10:40:00   10    10045    471
```

Here is some more Source Data:-
StartTime, Endtime, Asset, EventID, Duration
2014-10-01 10:29:50.000,    2014-10-01 10:32:09.000,    Asset01,    710,    138.9999998
2014-10-01 15:26:43.000,    2014-10-01 15:27:30.000,    Asset02,    10, 46.99999967
2014-10-01 15:26:44.000,    2014-10-01 15:36:44.000,    Asset02,    5760,   599.9999994
2014-10-01 16:33:48.000,    2014-10-01 16:43:49.000,    Asset01,    5760,   601.0000003
2014-10-01 16:33:48.000,    2014-10-01 16:34:35.000,    Asset01,    10, 47.0000003
2014-10-01 16:47:48.000,    2014-10-01 16:48:35.000,    Asset02,    10, 46.99999967
2014-10-01 20:55:20.000,    2014-10-01 20:56:07.000,    Asset02,    10, 47.0000003
2014-10-01 21:47:45.000,    2014-10-01 21:48:33.000,    Asset02,    10, 47.99999991
2014-10-01 23:04:12.000,    2014-10-01 23:05:00.000,    Asset02,    10, 47.99999991
2014-10-02 03:35:36.000,    2014-10-02 03:36:23.000,    Asset02,    10, 46.99999967
2014-10-02 04:56:22.000,    2014-10-02 04:57:09.000,    Asset01,    10, 46.99999967
2014-10-02 04:57:08.000,    2014-10-02 05:11:49.000,    Asset01,    6200,   880.9999997
2014-10-02 05:14:06.000,    2014-10-02 05:29:52.000,    Asset02,    6200,   945.9999999
2014-10-02 05:24:40.000,    2014-10-02 05:25:27.000,    Asset01,    10, 47.0000003
2014-10-02 06:15:06.000,    2014-10-02 06:15:53.000,    Asset02,    10, 47.0000003
2014-10-02 07:01:00.000,    2014-10-02 07:01:48.000,    Asset02,    10, 47.99999991
2014-10-02 11:34:58.000,    2014-10-02 11:35:45.000,    Asset02,    10, 46.99999967
2014-10-02 11:42:02.000,    2014-10-02 11:44:21.000,    Asset01,    65, 138.9999998
2014-10-02 14:43:35.000,    2014-10-02 14:44:22.000,    Asset01,    10, 47.0000003
2014-10-02 14:51:12.000,    2014-10-02 14:51:59.000,    Asset02,    10, 47.0000003
2014-10-03 12:00:00.000,    2014-10-03 12:00:47.000,    Asset02,    10, 47.0000003
2014-10-04 11:29:03.000,    2014-10-04 11:32:00.000,    Asset01,    68, 176.9999999
2014-10-05 04:51:19.000,    2014-10-06 21:15:33.000,    Asset02,    5000,   145454
2014-10-05 08:19:44.000,    2014-10-05 08:20:32.000,    Asset02,    10, 48.00000053
2014-10-05 08:26:34.000,    2014-10-05 08:27:21.000,    Asset01,    10,     46.99999967
I hope this makes sense

Many Thanks for taking the time to read this
Mark

Comment: You group on the columns that you are not aggregating:  Time, AssetID, EventID.   Also you have tagged both MySQL and SQL Server.  It can't be both, so which is it?

Comment: Its MSSQL 2012 not MySQL apologies for the typo, can you provide me with an example of the group please as I'm not sure how to get it to group at 10 minute intervals? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for something like

```
SUM (StartTime BETWEEN [calculated first time] AND [calculated last time]).
```

Does that help you? Or have i misunderstood your question?

Comment: I'm struggling with the splitting of the time over different 10 minutes periods and counting the number of seconds in each period.

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(StartTime DATETIME,EndTime DATETIME,AssetID INT,EventID INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP            

SELECT '2014/12/01 10:29:50',   '2014/12/01 10:32:09',     10 ,      10045
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014/12/01 10:29:55',   '2014/12/01 10:45:10',     11,       10046
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014/12/01 10:33:12',   '2014/12/01 11:01:45',     10,       10047
```

**QUERY**

Use a `recursive CTE` to get dates in between. Inside `CTE`, I have converted minute to next 10th minute in fraction of 10, ie minute-32 is converted to minute-40, minute-29 is converted to minute-30 etc

```
;WITH CTE AS
( 
     SELECT StartTime,EndTime,AssetID,EventID,
      -- Select the first word from Hour, cast to varchar, append with 0 to get next 10th minute
      MIN(DATEADD(MINUTE,10,CAST(CAST(CAST(StartTime AS DATE)AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' ' +
      CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,StartTime)AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':' +
      CAST(LEFT(RIGHT('0'+LEFT(DATEPART(MINUTE,StartTime),2),2),1) AS VARCHAR(2))+ '0' +':00' AS DATETIME)))NewStartTime,     
      MIN(DATEADD(MINUTE,10,CAST(CAST(CAST(EndTime AS DATE)AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' ' +
      CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,EndTime)AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':' +
      CAST(LEFT(RIGHT('0'+LEFT(DATEPART(MINUTE,EndTime),2),2),1) AS VARCHAR(2))+ '0' +':00' AS DATETIME)))NewEndTime           
      FROM #TEMP
      GROUP BY StartTime,EndTime,AssetID,EventID
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Find the difference in secnods with the 10th minute and orginal time
    SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(S,StartTime,NewStartTime) StartDiff,
    DATEDIFF(S,DATEADD(MINUTE,-10,NewEndTime),EndTime)EndDiff 
    FROM CTE
)
,CTE3 AS
(
  -- Recursive CTE(loop) to find in-between dates
  SELECT MIN(NewStartTime)StartTime,AssetID,EventID
  FROM CTE2
  GROUP BY AssetID,EventID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,10,C.StartTime),C.AssetID,C.EventID    
  FROM CTE3 C
  JOIN CTE2 T ON C.AssetID=T.AssetID AND C.EventID =T.EventID
  WHERE C.StartTime < NewEndTime
)
SELECT DISTINCT C3.*,
CASE 
  WHEN C3.StartTime=C2.NewStartTime THEN C2.StartDiff
  WHEN C3.StartTime=C2.NewEndTime THEN C2.EndDiff 
  ELSE 600
END AS ACT  
FROM CTE3 C3
LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON (C3.StartTime=C2.NewStartTime OR C3.StartTime=C2.NewEndTime)
AND C2.AssetID=C2.AssetID AND C3.EventID =C2.EventID
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8563a/1) to view result**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the query Rounding the minutes up to the next 10 minute block is exactly what I need, I've not used CTE before, with the above query I don't get the duration the Event was active in the given 10 minutes period, can you help and advise how I would add that please?  Many Thanks

Comment: All Sorted and working now, the code you supplied worked great I only needed to add the DateDiff(ss,StartTime,EndTime) into the query to solve my issues. your a Top SQL Guru Thank You.

Comment: I don't get the expected results with that query, working on 2 lines of data which are:-

Comment: I didn't get u? Can u elaborate. @Sh0t2bts

Comment: I don't get the expected results with that query, working on 2 lines of data which are:-<br>StartTime, EndTime, AssetID, EventID, Duration<br>2014/12/01 14:31:51, 2014/12/01 14:32:39 Asset01, 10, 48<br>2014/12/01 14:43:12, 2014/12/01 14:43:59 Asset01, 10, 47<br><br><br>The Result of the query gives me:-<br>StartTime, AssetID, EventID, Act<br>2014/12/01 14:40:00, Asset01, 10, 489<br>2014/12/01 14:50:00, Asset01, 10, 408<br><br> I don't see how your query is giving me 489 and 208 for the duration.  any Ideas?  Many Thanks Mark

Comment: There was a typo at the end of that last comment, I get 489 and 408 in the Act column were I'd expect 553 and 552 seconds as the Atc column results.

Comment: Result is correct. What is the diffeirence in seconds between **2014-12-01 14:31:51.000** and **2014-12-01 14:40:00.000** - its **489**. Does that make sense? For more details check - **SELECT DATEDIFF(S,'2014-12-01 14:31:51.000','2014-12-01 14:40:00.000') StartDiff** @Sh0t2bts

Comment: Maybe I've not given good examples, the details I'm after it the duration the Asset is in a none working state, that's what each of these entries represent, 14:31:51 to 14:40:00 is 489 seconds but the asset cam back on at 14:32:39, It was only off for 48 seconds of the 10 minute period, if it had stayed off longer and the EndTime was 14:41:00 then 489 would be the correct answer for that 14:40:00 10 minute period and 60 would then need allocating to the next 10 minute block at 14:50:00, as the asset wasn't off across two time periods only need the 48 seconds it was off.  Many Thanks Mark

Comment: Please modify the question and give more examples and criterias on which data has to be filtered. It would be very difficult to read from the comments. And leave me a message after you modify and add further details in question. I will be near you :) @Sh0t2bts

Comment: I saw the update. Is the new update for only same date or will  asset come back on next day? @Sh0t2bts

Comment: The Asset can be off for any period of time, i've included some more source data were the asset is off over night on the 4th Dec.... I hope this helps and Thank you so much for your help. Mark

Comment: K. I will update. May take some time. Will update u as soon as I complete :) @Sh0t2bts

Comment: Does the values(Duration) you added now should be the actual result or is Duration generated from my query? @Sh0t2bts

Comment: Please post what is your expected output for **Duration** and what is the result for **Duration** that you are getting from my query. @Sh0t2bts

Comment: Hello, One of the IT team has shut down my development server so I can't test your query on live data until Monday, looking at the result using the website it look to be exactly what I need, I will test it first thing in the morning on my Dev server and post an update... Thank you so much for your help..... Mark

Comment: K. Please update with exact requirement ie, you had mentioned the overlap issue later. So please make sure to include all such possibilities as well :) @Sh0t2bts

Comment: This works well when I have time stamps crossing the time period but not when the event starts and stops in the same time period, the time stamps I'm looking at are:-'01/12/2014 14:43:12' '01/12/2014 14:43:59' the query reports 408 seconds of running time, when I should be 553 which is 600 minus 47 seconds. the same for this time stamp range:- '01/12/2014 14:31:51' '01/12/2014 14:32:39' it's reports 489, which is the duration up to the start time not the difference between the start time and the end time, it appears to work well when the time stamp cross over the reporting period Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to round a `datetime` up to the next 10 minute interval, then the formula you can use is:

```
DATEADD(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute,0,<Value to Round>)/10+1)*10),0)
```

E.g. for the current time:

```
DATEADD(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/10+1)*10),0)
```

Just returned for me:

```
2015-01-16 08:00:00.000
```